# How can I change tab bar color in ConEmu

Tags: windows-explorer, conemu

How I can change color of tab bar in [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) on Windows? I tried find in settings but never found appropriate option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConEmu does not have such option because that is standard Windows control. Just change your Windows settings (if you can).

Comment: You right - this color depends on system global Button Background, what can be checked when applying High Contrast theme on Windows. To much sacrifice to get dark tabs :)

Comment: Do you confirm this is still the case? I'd like to make inactive tabs darker, because I can't easily see the active tab. My Windows colors are default AFAIK. Could you suggest a solution?

Comment: @Maximus Enabling different kinds of tabs might be an option. E.g. at the end of http://www.functionx.com/vccli/controls/tabcontrol.htm are two good examples of appearance that distinguishes the tabs enough: http://www.functionx.com/msdotnet/forms/tabappear1.gif and http://www.functionx.com/msdotnet/forms/tabappear2.gif. If given an option in ConEmu to choose between these, this could serve the same purpose - distinguishing tabs - in my opinion.

Comment: @steady Your examples are related to .Net. ConEmu is "WinApi" application and does not depend on any of external libraries. Anyway, proposed style looks ugly nowadays...

Answer (score 34):

You can make the active tab more visually distinct by dynamically modifying  its title.

Under Settings > General > Tab bar, you can set the `Console` setting to something like

```
%m< m%M(M%c%m >m%M)M %s
```

The `%m...m` block only appears on the active tab, while `%M...M` only appears on inactive tabs, giving you `< 1 > Tab name` on the active tab versus `(2) Tab name` on inactive tabs.  You can customize this styling however you want.

Another option is to prepend the unicode character of your choice before the active terminal, like so:

```
%mm (%c) %s
```

Or

```
%mm (%c) %s
```

Comment: Nice solution, I've just added `%m■m` to add a black square and make it more obvious which tab is the currently active one.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from Zags' suggestion, I came up with:

`%m◀m %s %f%m ▶m`

[image]